# Theano and pygpu: errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, cuda, theano, theano-cuda

I'm using Theano with pygpu.

Generally, it works well until, for reasons I still haven't managed to understand, it shows the following error once I try to import theano:

```
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/poko/Software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 220, in <module>
    use(config.device)
  File "/home/poko/Software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 207, in use
    init_dev(device, preallocate=preallocate)
  File "/home/poko/Software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 94, in init_dev
    **args)
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 651, in pygpu.gpuarray.init
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 587, in pygpu.gpuarray.pygpu_init
GpuArrayException: cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
```

If I reboot my computer, it works well again, for a while (sometimes for days..).

Now that situation is strange, given that such things either do work, or don't.
I have not the faintest about what is generating the error, apart from observing from nvidia-smi that xorg and chrome do suck quite a lot of memory:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1332      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           392MiB |
|    0      2243      G   cinnamon                                     110MiB |
|    0      4927      G   ...-token=39C210A3DFA14C5D81FA629C813B843D   154MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: look for zombie processes in the failed state

Comment: Ok, thanks. I rebooted now (and it works again), but I'll check upon the next error. However, before rebooting, I did a ps ax | grep theano, and it showed nothing.

Comment: Ok, I checked carefully. No zombie processes at all. Plus, putting the computer into suspend-to-ram is a sufficient (although NOT necessary) condition for getting theano/pygpu out of order, and the only thing that seems able to get it up and running is a reboot. I'm really struggling with that, mate..

Comment: This sounds like a driver/hardware/OS problem, rather than anything related to CUDA *programming* and is probably off-topic for [SO]

Comment: Where should it be asked? Serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I can get rid of the error just by unloading **nvidia_uvm** module, by doing:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
```

after which, it will be automatically reloaded.

Hope this helps should someone else incur in that problem.